# Getting VBA Error 1004 when referenced sheet is not actives

Tags: excel, vba

The code snippet below is giving the run time error '1004' while 'Data' sheets is not active and runs fine when active.

```vb
Worksheets("Data").Range(Cells(10, 1), Cells(10, 8)) = "blah"
```

What is the error?

Comment: You are not specifying the worksheet in `Cells` so it is defaulting to the active sheet.

Comment: I am mentioning the 'Data' worksheet in first place itself , can you rectify the code and share ??

Comment: You only qualify the `Range()` - that doesn't "carry over" to the `Cells()` inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following from comments above:

```vb
With Worksheets("Data")
    .Range(.Cells(10, 1), .Cells(10, 8)).Value = "blah"
End With
```